# RequireJS - protecting my jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

We're implementing a large site that has a ton of tracking on it.  There is one particular 3rd-party tracking company that's including jquery for their tagging.

They are calling `jQuery.noConflict(true)`; which is removing `window.$` and `window.jQuery`.

My site is organized using RequireJS and I've implemented the config mapping for jquery found [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap):

```
requirejs.config({
    // Add this map config in addition to any baseUrl or
    // paths config you may already have in the project.
    map: {
      // '*' means all modules will get 'jquery-private'
      // for their 'jquery' dependency.
      '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },

      // 'jquery-private' wants the real jQuery module
      // though. If this line was not here, there would
      // be an unresolvable cyclic dependency.
      'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    }
});

// and the 'jquery-private' module, in the
// jquery-private.js file:
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

I'm wondering how I can protect all of my code from this 3rd-party plugin's squashing `window.jQuery`.

Do I need to wrap each plugin in an AMD wrapper with something along the lines of:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
     // plugin library goes here
});
```

Or is there some global method of doing this?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the jQuery plugins you've made, then this would be the correct solution.

If you're asking about the 3rd party plugins, you could add a shim configuration for each plugin:

```
requirejs.config({
    map: {
      '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },
      'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    },
    shim: {
        'a-jquery-plugin': ['jquery']
    }
});
```

From the [official docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) about `shim`:

> Configure the dependencies, exports, and custom initialization for
>   older, traditional "browser globals" scripts that do not use define()
>   to declare the dependencies and set a module value.

There is an example for jQuery plugins in the docs as well:

> For "modules" that are just jQuery or Backbone plugins that do not need to export any module value, the shim config can just be an array of dependencies:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'jquery.colorize': ['jquery'],
        'jquery.scroll': ['jquery'],
        'backbone.layoutmanager': ['backbone']
    }
});
```

Here are some key notes from the docs:

> - The shim config only sets up code relationships. To load modules that are part of or use shim config, a normal require/define call is
>     needed. Setting shim by itself does not trigger code to load.
> - If it is not possible to upgrade the shimmed code to use AMD define() calls, as of RequireJS 2.1.11, the optimizer has a `wrapShim`
>     build option that will try to automatically wrap the shimmed code in a
>     define() for a build. This changes the scope of shimmed dependencies,
>     so it is not guaranteed to always work, but, for example, for shimmed
>     dependencies that depend on an AMD version of Backbone, it can be
>     helpful.
> - Shim config is not supported when running AMD modules in node via RequireJS (it works for optimizer use though). Depending on the module
>     being shimmed, it may fail in Node because Node does not have the same
>     global environment as browsers. As of RequireJS 2.1.7, it will warn
>     you in the console that shim config is not supported, and it may or
>     may not work. If you wish to suppress that message, you can pass
>     `requirejs.config({ suppress: { nodeShim: true }});`.

Comment: Wow. I actually learned something today. And it's not even a problem for me.

Comment: I am using the shim, but the underlying problem is that almost every plugin initializes on window.jQuery.  How do I get around this?  I guess I can set my own window property to be, say, jq and find/replace each plugin's window.jQuery with window.jq.....

Comment: If every plugin specifically references `window.jQuery`, and not `jQuery` or `$`, you could create your own `window` module which would have a property `jQuery` with your private jQuery instance. You could then shim the plugin by specifying `['window]` as a shim value, instead of `jQuery`.